# SQL left join table with double sum record

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables (dw and click) and using `left join` to join it if match the date. 
both tables have date 2016-06-01 (dw table has 1 record and click table has 2 records). I want to `sum` the column winloss in dw table, but since click table has 2 record with the date 2016-06-01 and caused the winloss double sum. But i just want sum the winloss in dw table. Any suggestion? Please refer to image below.

[image: sql (Image)]

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Do you need any fields from click table?

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: @Joe: yes, i jsut need click column.

Comment: @ Squirrel: Expected dont sum the winloss after join click table

Comment: please show us your expected result

Comment: None of the given answers seem particularly good, which is funny, because this is a very basic question. Look, all you want to do is get the value in one table if it exists in another table, right? There's a plethora of ways you could do this and you don't even need a join for it. I would suggest looking into, for example, how `EXISTS` works in SQL, or how `GROUP BY` works if you wish to use a join.

Comment: Do you mean you need the clicked column?  What logic do you want to decide to keep 21 vs 2?  Or do you want to sum that as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a temp table or a common table expression. Here is with a temp.

```
If object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null drop table #temp


select
sum(winloss) as winloss,
updated
--add any other columns you want
into #temp
group by
updated
--add other columns to group


select
t.updated,
t.winloss,
c.*
from #temp t
left join click on c.trandate = t.updated
```

Comment: The click table has 2 record for date (2016-01-01), even save into temp table, when join to the click table, it also will sum 2 record, but I just want the summation of the winloss column in dw table.

Comment: The sum is only done on the dw table grouped on date. It doesn't sum anything based on click

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to sum the two records of the same date?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DW D
INNER JOIN CLICK C
ON C.CLICKED = D.CLICKCOUNT
AND C.TRANDATE = D.UPDATED
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT  dw.[updated]
  ,sum(distinct [winloss])
from dw,Click
where dw.updated = Click.trandate 
FROM dw, Click
group by dw.updated
```